# Kick command access to everyone

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

So the code below is my Kick.js but I want it so that the mod role can only use the kick command

```
module.exports = {
    name: 'kick', //command name run : async(client,
message, args) => {
        if (!message.guild.me.hasPermission('KICK_MEMBER')) return message.channel.send('I do not have permission to use this command
 :joy: ');
         // Basically checks if the bot has permission to kick a member or not

         //Lets define the guildmember to kick!

         const Member = message.mentions.members.first() //checking for member mentions
         if (!Member) return message.channel.send('Please specify a member to kick.....');
        // if there is no user then it will return with that message 
await Member.kick({ reason: args.slice(1).join(" ")})
        // args.slice(1).join(" ") means it slices the Member Variable and takes the text after it.
message.channel.send(`${ Member.user.tag}
            was kicked from the server!`)
        // above message will be sent when the member is kicked from the server.
    }
}
```

Comment: Make sure only the mod role has the KICK_MEMBER permission.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check for the message.member permissions

```js
if(!message.member.hasPermission("KICK_MEMBERS")) 
   return message.reply("You don't have enough permissions for kick")
```

If you want to check for specific role

```js
if(!message.member.roles.cache.has(modRole)) 
   return message.reply("You aren't a Mod")
```

Comment: The second example doesn't work in Discord.JS v12 anymore.